# Unexpected Log Shipping Error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, log-shipping

I was trying to Configure Log shipping through SSMS (SQL server Management Studio) in between Failover Cluster Instance (Principal Server) and Standalone (Secondary Server), Once I click OK button to finish the Log Shipping configuration, Backup on Primary completed successfully but for Restore to secondary it throws error. I am using existing Drives with required Permissions granted.

Error message:
[image]

It means I need to Create a separate folder and assign permissions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58905/discussion-on-question-by-cr241-unexpected-log-shipping-error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize what we hashed out in the comments, yes, you will first need to [setup a file share](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2012/10/21/12-steps-to-ntfs-shared-folders-in-windows-server-2012/) with proper permissions as part of the Prerequisites outlined in the [Configure Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/configure-log-shipping-sql-server) Guide provided by Microsoft.

Once you have the fileshare created, you should be able to connect to it using a UNC path similar to `\\servername\sharedFolder`